# How can I force a disconnection in Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to disconnect manually my clients from my chat. Let me show my basic code :

```
...

<h1>welcome to my chat</h1>

<script>
$(function(){

    var mySocket = io.connect('/game1/roomGame);

    $('#force').click(function(event){
    mySocketdisconnect();
    })


});
</script>
```

In my server:

```
    mySocket.on('disconnect', function(){
             console.log(" disconnection forced ");
    });
```

In my console, when leaving the route `/game1/roomGame` , certainly, I see the message `disconnection forced`, but I'm sure the disconnection isn't really done because I see also in my console somes messages like:

```
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client f8oj63XfQ7T8mbNFP8SR
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client f8oj63XfQ7T8mbNFP8SR
   debug - got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client f8oj63XfQ7T8mbNFP8SR
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client f8oj63XfQ7T8mbNFP8SR
```

How can I close literraly this connection ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `mySocketRoom.socket.disconnect()`.  Expose that as `disconnect` on your service:

```
return {
  ...
  disconnect: function() { mySocketRoom.socket.disconnect(); }
};
```

Also, if your gameRoom lasts only as long as the user is in a certain controller, `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess` seem too general.

I would just disconnect whenever the controller $scope is destroyed.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  mySocketRoom.disconnect();
});
```

Documentation: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$destroy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24destroy)

Comment: When I tried to test your code I have already adapted it :). I think my problem has nothing to do with Angulars.js. I think it's an issue with Socket.io

Comment: This solution will fix it.  You need the socket object on the socket object.

Eg. `var mySocket = io.connect(); mySocket.socket.disconnect();`

Comment: I have tried both `mySocket.disconnect();` and `mySocket.socket.disconnect();` but they doesn't work. Finally I have tested this solution `io.sockets['http://localhost:3000'].disconnect();` and it works great !!!